# Bitmap consumed RAM memory isn't released after recycle

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I use below code to reduce bitmap size and save it memory. But when I use it, the consumed RAM memory isn't releases. What's the solution? I called System.gc() after usting below method, but does not affect.

```
public static void compress_save(Bitmap input, String path, int dim) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path);
    input = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(input, Generals.img_width, Generals.img_height, true);
    input.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, dim, out);

    out.flush();
    out.close();
    input.recycle();
}
```

I call above function in activity result

```
 Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                imgPath = Util.getRealPathFromURI(MainActivity.this, selectedImageUri);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath);
                try {
                    imgPath = Generals.App_Directory + "/temp/" + SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis();
                    ImageUtil.compress_save(bitmap, imgPath, 50);
                    bitmap.recycle();
                    System.gc();
                    confirmDialog();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    FileLogException.print(e);
                }
```

Comment: you are not recycling the bigger bitmap (`Bitmap input` parameter)

Comment: have you tried using `MAT` to check who's still holding the reference?

Comment: once again, use MAT and see who holds the reference to the bitmap, calling System.gc doesn't actually cause gc

Comment: All thing about the bitmap is that I used there that have mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about thing I say,But I think when you call recycle if your device has enough RAM memory keeps the bitmap in the RAM and when RAM space is low the bitmap RAM memory releases.

I tested on two devices these code. When my devices had much memory after recycling bitmap RAM space doesn't release but when device has low memory after recycling bitmap RAM memory release.